On macOS Eclipse 2024-03 wastes space, how to change?
As documented in https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1864776/#msg_1864776 due to some changes
there is now a lot of space wasted - see the before and after! Does anybody know on how to revert this back?


See https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/issues/1674#issuecomment-2017386631 and the comments below.

See Eclipse Platform issue #1674 the following comment by Martin Lippert:

I think the fix will be part of the 2024-06 release. If you want to
fix this in a running 2024-03 installation, I would follow the steps
described in #1674 (comment). Worked for me quite nicely.

For security reasons, better avoid the hotfix and wait for the first milestone of Eclipse 2024-06, which will be available soon on Friday, April 12, 2024.
